# Pairwise isomorphic groups of the same order

Tags: finite-groups, group-isomorphism

I know those cases exist for groups of order $n,n$ is prime but what if n is not prime?

Can we find such $n=p_1 p_2 ...$, so every 2 groups of order n are pairwise isomorphic?

The first isomorphism theorem might play a role here but I can't find a way to begin.

Comment: Yes, the prime numbers.

Comment: but surely you have to get more than 1 group of the same order to begin with, if n is a prime then there will be one group only?

Comment: Only one group *up to isomorphism*. But that's what you're looking for. You could define two groups of order $5$: $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and they will be isomorphic.

Comment: @Riley Thank you, that solves my problem.

Comment: I have not edited the problem to deal with non-prime n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every finite number $n$, the following conditions are equivalent:

1. There is only one group of order $n$ up to isomorphism (necessarily the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$).
2. $n$ is a product of distinct primes $n = p_1p_2\dots p_k$ such that for all $i$ and $j$, $p_i$ does not divide $p_j-1$.

For example, this is true whenever $n$ is a prime number. The smallest non-prime example is $15$. Indeed, $15 = 3\times 5$, and $3$ does not divide $4 = 5-1$.

See [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_cyclicity-forcing_numbers) for more information.

Comment: This is one of my favorite group theory facts.

Comment: I like the other condition more : "it is relatively prime to the value of its totient function'". But, $+1$.